# How to model this classes/database tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, oop, database-design

I have to model classes and database tables for a "User" entity.

This "User" entity have this properties:

```
User
  Name
  Age
  Gender
  Email
```

But I have 2 user's type: "Paid users" and "Free users". Each one have his own properties:

```
Paid User
  Fee  
  Rate

Free User
  Expiration Date
  Level
```

"Paid User" and "Free User" are different, but both are "User".

I'm using ASP.NET MVC, NHibernate and Fluent Maps.

What is the best way and the right design pattern to model this classes and database tables?

Thank you very much!

Comment: With EF, you could set the types of users right on the model designer based on certain conditions. Just a suggestion. Dunno bout NHibernate.

Answer (score 3):

I often find the best approach for this is to use an inheritance model. All common fields go into the `User` table. You create an entry in `User` first, and then use the resulting `UserID` to create additional entries in `Paid User` or `Free User` as necessary.

```
User 
  UserID
  Name 
  Age 
  Gender 
  Email 

Paid User 
  UserID <-- FK to User
  Fee   
  Rate 

Free User 
  UserID <-- FK to User
  Expiration Date 
  Level
```

Then you can select (or create a `VIEW`) like this:

```
select u.UserID, U.Name, ...
    pu.Fee, pu.Rate,
    fu.ExpirationDate, fu.Level,
    case when pu.UserID is null then 0 else 1 end as IsPaidUser,
    case when fu.UserID is null then 0 else 1 end as IsFreeUser
from User u
left outer join PaidUser pu on u.UserID = pu.UserID
left outer join FreeUser fu on u.UserID = fu.UserID
```

Note: The above schema is pretty naive and doesn't handle cases where a user could be a free user, then a paid user, then a free user again. How you design for this really depends on your application and business rules.

Comment: This is how I would do it. You might also want to add a trigger on the PaidUser and FreeUser tables to ensure that a given user does not exist in both tables.

Comment: Agree with Mike Forman's comment.  Also, you might want to add a field in the User table to indicate whether it is a Paid User or Free User.

Comment: @mbeckish: perhaps a user could be both...I have added columns in the select that let you know if the User is one or the other...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that in your Object model User would be considered abstract consider the following User table definition:

> User
>   ID
>   Name
>   Age
>   Gender
>   Email
>   Type  <-- Free/Paid/etc
>
> Paid User
>   ID
>   UserID <--- FK to User table
>   Fee
>   Rate
>
> Free User
>   ID
>   UserID <--- FK to User table
>   Expiration Date
>   Level

This will allow you to query in this fashion:

> Select * from User where Type = Free

Answer (score 0):

What operations for theese user types?

Any design should start from operations then data structures, not conversely.

Comment: I, basicly, need to redirect user to right content, base on user type. Thanks.

Comment: Use flag (bool) for Free\Paid.